# Unable To Access File In IIS 6 Virtual Folder From Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have a website sitting in a virtual directory in IIS 6.0. Within this virtual diretory there is also a P12 certification that I need to use for accessing an external web service. When I attempt to access this file through the site, I get a "file not found" error.

I have verified that the file is there and have mirrored my local dev enviromnent to match production and all works fine there.

I'm pretty confident that this is a permissions issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're confident it's a permissions issue, have you tried changing the permissions on that file to grant read access to the aspnet process?

Comment: Hi Josh. IIS is running under Local System and the app pool is running under a domain account. I've added both of these and granted full rights to both the file and the entire web folder to no avail.

I'm open to the idea that it's not a permissions issue but it works fine on my dev box which is configured identically (except using my security context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the message of the exception is misleading. The message says was File Not Found but the message was contained within a System.CryptogrphyException. Ultimately, the problem was permissions on the app pool account. Once those were set properly, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>By default, IIS 6 will only serve specific types of files (based on extension) to requesting clients. If you're P12 certification (I'm not sure what that is) file is not one of those, a 404 is exactly what you should receive.</strike>

In your IIS admin console, you can modify the list of file types which are processed and/or served.

It sounds like it's possible you're attempting to access this file programmatically, in which case you'll need to provide a bit more information - show us the code that is attempting to access the file, and maybe the exception as well

EDIT:

Based on your comments about the location of the file, you could try doing something along the lines of this:

`File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/") + "DLWSCert.p12")`

Comment: Hi Josh The code is prett simple. The below simply fails if (!(File.Exists(certLocation))) { throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Cannot locate {0}.", SiteConfig.CertLocation)); }

Comment: can you post the physical file path along with the value of `certLocation` at the time of the check? Are they different?

Comment: Hi Josh
The p12 is in the same folder as the site's Default.aspx

 C:\inetput\wwwroot\mysite\DLWSCert.p12

Comment: Ok...I've narrowed it down to failing on this call... clientCert = new X509Certificate2(this._wsCertLocation, this._wsCertPassword);...The plot sickens...

Comment: I'm confused. Is this the same code that was throwing the error previously, or is the previous code now working and this represents a different error?

Comment: Hi Josh. I believe I was confused. Its the later one that isn't working. The File.Exists is working. Sorry about that.